# iOS - Autolayout - View overlaps Top layout

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have the following storyboard.

## The Hierarchy

[image: Hierarchy]

## When I select View

[image: View selected]

## When I select Image Avatar

[image]

How can I put View bellow Top Layout?

Answer (score 1):

Set constraints to top as 0 if view is top layout or as 20 if [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyZ8Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

That view is the Main View of the View Controller, when you select that 
View it shows the total area covered by that view. Since it is the main view it covers the whole area of the View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to face this challenge was clear constraints.
Click on

`Resolve Autolayout Issues` -> `Clear Constraints`